# How do I figure out what was merged into my branch and when

Tags: svn, subclipse

I've inherited a Subversion repository that is a bit of a mess.  I am on a single branch and am trying to figure out when the changeslists from a different branch were merged it.  What's the best way to go about this?

In subclipse, on the History tab, each revision has a window that shows Action, Affected paths, and Description.  Some of these Descriptions are like "from /BLAHBLAH/branches/integration/config/log4j.xml".  I've been using them as clues that a merge was in progress, but I've seen check-ins with comments like "merge from integration(1766) to feature-1798" that suggest a merge was being done but I see no tell-tale "from /BLAHBLAH/branches/integration/config/log4j.xml".

I am at a loss for figuring out what commits represent merges from one branch to another.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the drop-down menu in the History view and check the item "Include Merged Revisions".  This will cause each revision from your branch that committed a merge to be an expandable tree that show the revisions that were merged in that commit.

Comment: You know, I don't get the "expandable tree" part in my History tab, but I do now see a column "Merged Revisions" that has a comma-delimited list of what got merged in.  Any idea how to do essentially the same thing from the command line?  The comma-delimited list does indeed seem to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: You are right, it displays a list, and there is a Show Merged Revisions right-click option.  You get the same thing from the command line using svn log -g.  Of course you have to parse the output because it will be in log format.